# Integrate wordpress blog into asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

I have developed a blog for one of my client using wordpress. Now i need to integrate the blog into their website which was developed using .net based cms platform.

I need to retain the header and footer of the website in the blog section.

It is difficult and time consuming to do header and footer for the blog to look consistent with the site.

Is there a better way by which i can integrate the blog into website and retain the website header and footer?

Note: I cant embed using `iframe` as the blog must be included in the horizontal Menu section (developed using sprites) of the website.

Comment: I doubt there are any direct conversion tools for the code, it sounds like you just need to re-implement the design into the client's CMS structure.  "Difficult and time consuming" notwithstanding, if the use of their CMS is a requirement of the project then you have to use their CMS.

Comment: @David Thank you for the reply,i am redesigning the whole header and footer for the blog to look consistent with the website. I have modified the menu of the website by including the blog section. But when i click on the blog menu, it successfully links me to the blog. But the blog doesnt have the header and footer of the site.

Comment: In IIS , i have create 2 sites differently. 1 for the website and 1 for blog. Do  i have to create blog as subdomain to website?

Comment: Separate sub-domain is the way to go, see answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to take the blog design and skin their existing site the same way. Then use a sub-domain for the Wordpress blog. It should appear seamless. I did the same here with BlogEngine and existing site:

Main site: http://homenetdirect.com

Blog: http://blog.homenetdirect.com/

Comment: I cant redesign their website , i need to design the blog according to their website using WordPress. I get the content of the blog successfully when i click on the blog menu from the website except header and footer. I just need to get the header and footer of the website .  The website is a multilanguage (english and french) and so the blog too has the multilanguage.

Comment: Not saying to re-design their website. I'm saying to skin Wordpress the same as their site.

Comment: @IrishChieftain: It sounds like it's more than a skinning, though.  The main site has dynamic functionality (language selection, for example) that the blog also needs.  It really sounds to me like the blog should have been implemented directly in the main site, not as a separate application instance on an entirely different CMS platform.

Comment: I am new to asp.net and wordpress . Can you give me some idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @curious_webprogrammer: I'm seeing two options: (1) The Wordpress site needs to access their CMS data to populate the dynamic header/footer content.  This basically means entirely re-implementing their structure in the Wordpress site.  Or (2) the blog needs to be re-implemented in their existing CMS system to make use of the existing functionality.  Ultimately, if their existing system is ASP.NET, introducing a dependency on Wordpress may not have been a good idea.  The biggest question for the project is whether or not these requirements were known before that decision was made.

Comment: You only need to add a single blog link to the existing site menu. As for multi-language feature - you would have to probably create another sub-domain for this other version of the blog and skin that also.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will be doing that.