# Display header and footer in 2 languages

Tags: wordpress

I have solved the problem of including header and footer of the website( developed in asp.net)in the blog (developed in wordpress)by taking the suggestions from professionals in my previous question [Integrate wordpress blog into asp.net website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14124059/1871419)

Now the header ( the sprites menu section)  and footer (has three columns: products, menu and contact-us)are displaying in one language .

Can i have header.php and footer.php in 2 languages(English and French)?

I have used polylang plugin for multilang. But i have not used dashboard or widgets to display main menu and footer. I have included the code in header.php  and footer.php

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on the way that WordPress implement the multilingual interface. Howver, the common way to implement multilingual is to supply a url parameter indicates the current active language like [this example](http://umcuqu.com). You will find something like:

```
mysite.com/fr/ for French section
```

So, by using AJAX you could able to get the footer of the other language and place it with your current language footer. In other word, this solution depends on AJAX.

Comment: I was trying the following code in footer.php and header.php                        <?php $lingo=strtolower(substr(get_locale(),0,2));
 if($lingo=="en"): ?> "english menu ( in header.php) and english footer(in footer.php)"                                                <?php endif; ?>                                                   <?php elseif($lingo=="fr"): ?>"english menu ( in header.php) and english footer(in footer.php)"                                                <?php endif; ?>                                                      but it doesnt work.

Comment: sorry if(lingo=='fr') french menu and french footer . Typing mistake